# Understanding customary  usage(s?) of “FYI”

Tags: abbreviations

Can anyone demonstrate the various usages of *FYI*, meaning the *“for your information”* thing? It would be great to see it in different kinds of sentences!

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate of [Is it appropriate to treat fyi as a noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21770), but John's answer is more interesting than those already at that question.  Also see [Are the acronyms fyi btw lol wtf now considered normal words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1908)

Comment: Yes, there's someone who can find LOTS of usages of "FYI" for you.  His name is Google.

Answer (score 3):

In English speech, *"FYI"*, pronounced /ɛfwayay/, can be used like a [Class II Adverbial Subordinating Conjunction](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf), and can be modified by *just*.

- *(Just) FYI, she is **not** his girlfriend.*

In English writing, *"FYI"* is a [TLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym), and may be used like any common non-literary abbreviation, wherever formality is less important than letter count.

In both cases, however, the speaker (or writer) is assuming a **Personalized** (*wink, wink; nudge, nudge*) stance with respect to the listener (or reader), which reminds one somewhat of Tom Lehrer's story about

> "a letter I received which said: 
>    *Darling, I love you and I cannot live without you. Marry me, or I will kill myself.* Well, I was a little disturbed at that, until I took another look at the envelope and saw that it was addressed to *Occupant*."

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking for situations where *FYI* could be used? Because surely it can attach on the the end, or beginning, of any (informal) sentence where the speaker want to impart some information on his/her listener.